# C++ cout hex values?

Tags: c++, hex, cout

I want to do:

```
int a = 255; 
cout << a;
```

and have it show FF in the output, how would I do this?

Answer (score 271):

Use:

```
#include <iostream>

...

std::cout << std::hex << a;
```

There are [many other options to control the exact formatting of the output number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), such as leading zeros and upper/lower case.

Comment: This seems to change all future output from cout to hex; so if you only want 'a' to be printed in hex you may want something like `cout << hex << a << dec;` to change it back.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR One problem with restoring dec over hex is that dec may not have been the value previously set, especially if you're writing a generic library method. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2273330/461834) has some answers about how to store and restore state. You can save state with `ios::fmtflags f(cout.flags());` and restore it with `out.flags(f);`.

Comment: Then restore by `std::cout.flags(f);`

Answer (score 50):

To manipulate the stream to print in hexadecimal use the `hex` manipulator:

```
cout << hex << a;
```

By default the hexadecimal characters are output in lowercase. To change it to uppercase use the `uppercase` manipulator:

```
cout << hex << uppercase << a;
```

To later change the output back to lowercase, use the `nouppercase` manipulator:

```
cout << nouppercase << b;
```

Comment: Is `nouppercase` going to change the output back to decimal?

Comment: Just to add miscellaneous note, the above snippet won't make an input "apple" becoming "APPLE".

Answer (score 48):

`std::hex` is defined in `<ios>` which is included by `<iostream>`. But to use things like `std::setprecision/std::setw/std::setfill`/etc you have to include `<iomanip>`.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to print a single hex number, and then revert back to decimal you can use this:

```
std::cout << std::hex << num << std::dec << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 27):

I understand this isn't what OP asked for, but I still think it is worth to point out how to do it with printf. I almost always prefer using it over std::cout (even with no previous C background).

```
printf("%.2X", a);
```

'2' defines the precision, 'X' or 'x' defines case.

Comment: There's long been a printf vs cout battle. Of course, cout has the nice property that it derives from ostream and gets all the abstraction benefits. C has no concept of stream objects and thus printf and fprintf are 2 different commands. Really, it would have been nice in C if stdout were a FILE*. Would have made things easier.

Comment: @rlbond stdout is a FILE * in C.

Comment: Which is why `printf("hello\n")` is equivalent to `fprintf(stdout, "hello\n")`. More usefully, you can pass `stdout` (or `stdin`, or `stderr`) to a function that takes a `FILE*` argument.

Comment: for anyone thinking that `cout` is a bliss - read the answers here. upper case? back to dec? flags? masks? you get hundred unresolved questions to only printing a number.. and std::format is still not implemented (2022!).. while `printf` gives you one definitive answer and is fast!

Answer (score 20):

`std::hex` gets you the hex formatting, but it is a stateful option, meaning you need to save and restore state or it will impact all future output.

Naively switching back to `std::dec` is only good if that's where the flags were before, which may not be the case, particularly if you're writing a library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

...

std::ios_base::fmtflags f( cout.flags() );  // save flags state
std::cout << std::hex << a;
cout.flags( f );  // restore flags state
```

This combines Greg Hewgill's answer and info from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2273352/461834).

Answer (score 15):

**C++20 `std::format`**

This is now the cleanest method in my opinion, as it does not pollute `std::cout` state with `std::hex`:

main.cpp

```
#include <format>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{:x} {:#x} {}\n", 16, 17, 18);
}
```

Expected output:

```
10 0x11 18
```

Not yet implemented on GCC 10.0.1, Ubuntu 20.04.

But the awesome library that became C++20 and should be the same worked once installed on Ubuntu 22.04 with:

```
sudo apt install libfmt-dev
```

or:

```
git clone https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt
cd fmt
git checkout 061e364b25b5e5ca7cf50dd25282892922375ddc
mkdir build
cmake ..
sudo make install
```

main2.cpp

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:x} {:#x} {}\n", 16, 17, 18);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main2.out main2.cpp -lfmt
./main2.out
```

Documented at:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification

More info at: [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf/57286312#57286312)

**Pre-C++20: cleanly print and restore `std::cout` to previous state**

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ios oldState(nullptr);
    oldState.copyfmt(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout << 16 << std::endl;
    std::cout.copyfmt(oldState);
    std::cout << 17 << std::endl;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

Output:

```
10
17
```

More details: [Restore the state of std::cout after manipulating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273330/restore-the-state-of-stdcout-after-manipulating-it/30968371#30968371)

Tested on GCC 10.0.1, Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, you can check the status of standard library support at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support. This feature shows up as "Text formatting".

Comment: @TylerKropp nice table, I wasn't too aware of it!

Comment: std::format wouldn't work on latest gcc / clang - https://godbolt.org/z/33nP7G3qT

Comment: It's a shame that it's been almost 2 years and gcc still does not support `std::format`. It's very useful.

Answer (score 13):

There are different kinds of flags & masks you can use as well. Please refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/setf/ for more information.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 255;
    cout.setf(ios::hex, ios::basefield);
    cout << "Hex: " << num << endl;

    cout.unsetf(ios::hex);
    cout << "Original format: " << num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the behavior of this code is undefined. The setf clears the ios::basefield bits, including ios::dec (default for standard streams), and sets only ios::hex. When ios::hex is unset, every bit in ios::basefield is unset. How it num printed the second time? evidence that the bits are all unset: http://ideone.com/fYXyh6. This is permitted for ios::floatfield according to Thinking in C++ vol 2 page 189, but it doesn't say the same about ios::basefield.

Comment: The code assumes that `ios::hex` was not set when calling it

Answer (score 9):

Use `std::uppercase` and `std::hex` to format integer variable `a` to be displayed in hexadecimal format.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   int a = 255;

   // Formatting Integer
   std::cout << std::uppercase << std::hex << a << std::endl; // Output: FF
   std::cout << std::showbase  << std::hex << a << std::endl; // Output: 0XFF
   std::cout << std::nouppercase << std::showbase  << std::hex << a << std::endl; // Output: 0xff

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

How are you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

unsigned char arr[] = {4, 85, 250, 206};
for (const auto & elem : arr) {
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') 
              << std::setw(2) 
              << std::uppercase 
              << std::hex 
              << (0xFF & elem) 
              << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++23 you can use [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print) to do this:

```cpp
int a = 255; 
std::print("{:X}", a);
```

This method is faster, less verbose than using I/O manipulators and doesn't affect the global formatting state. You can also print to `cout` although this will loose some of the perf benefits.

Until `std::print` is widely available you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), it is based on ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/feenfb7Mh)):

```cpp
fmt::print("{:X}", a);
```

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of {fmt} and C++23 `std::print`.