# Printing the hex value of an array to a string using C++

Tags: c++, string, hex

Using standard C++ I/O (such as `std::cout`), is it possible to "print" the value of an array (however long) into a string?

For example, say I have the following array:

```
unsigned long C = {0x497fecf2, 0xfa989ea3, 0xd594974e};
```

I'd like to be able to print those values into a string, and then remove the "`0x`" from them. From another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values), I've found how to print hex values with `cout`.

Is what I'm asking possible the way I've described?

Would it be better to just go back to an old comp sci assignment for base conversions, and convert the decimal value into hex, using a lookup table to add the appropriate next hexit to the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `std::ostringstream`, and print them to it just like you could to `cout`. Retrieve the string with the contents with the stringstream's `str()` member.

Comment: I knew it couldn't be that hard - just didn't know where to look. Thanks