# When printing hex values using %x why is 'ffffff' printed after each value?

Tags: c++

In a sample c++ code I will open a file and print each char in hexa
file has only 16 chars but why ffffff will print after each heax values?

```
char buff[256];
// buff filled with fread
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
printf("%x",buff[i]);
```

Output is:

```
4affffff67ffffffcdffffff
```

Why is this?

Comment: Show us the full code, specifically, what `buff` is and how it is filled with data.

Comment: For the love of bacon, _PLEASE_ don't add tags that do not apply to your question.  You stated it is C++ code (though I'd argue it's really C code) but you added other languages... don't do that.

Comment: Please label valid C code as such, and only as such. Other people browsing the site could otherwise think this is good/common/canonical/etc. C++ code.

Comment: See this [thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit:

```
 printf("%x",  (int)(*(unsigned char*)(&buff[i])) );
```

This should make the trick. My first version was incorrect, sorry. The problem is in the sign bit: every value more than 127 was handled as negative. Casting to unsigned char should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for u r quick reply . But after adding (int) also its printing ffffff

Comment: Please show buff variable definition.

Comment: buff is filed by fread()

Comment: Thanks Alex,  printf("%x",  (int)(*(unsigned char*)(&buff[i])) );
Is solved my probelm.

Comment: The outer cast should be to `unsigned int`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%x", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)buff[i]);
```

Explanation:

`printf` will first convert char to int for you. If your char is signed (first bit is 1) - e.g. `10000001` - then sign extension will preserve the value when converting to int: `11111111 11111111 11111111 10000001`. The fix is to convert it yourself first (without sign extension).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11911005)

Comment: true ... explanation added