# I want to convert the hex value in the character array to integer

Tags: c++

I want to convert the hex value in the `character array` to an `integer`.

```
int main()
{ 
    char arr[5];
    arr[0] = 0x05;
    int a = atoi(&arr[0]);
    cout << "Number = " << a; //output = 0 but i want here value 5  
}
```

Comment: You don't need `atoi`

Comment: `atoi` -> `convert a string to an integer`. So, at this step, `arr[0]= 0x05;` is 0x05 a string/character? No, it's a hex number. Then do you expect atoi work? No. Check this, probably it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values

Comment: but how can i get 5 in the integer variable?

Comment: `int a = 0xFF; ` this will put the hex value in the int. int is a data type, like a container. `0x` is a base specification, like you are putting water into that container through a garden hose or a glass. But ultimately, only thing that matters is how much water is there. Read K&R

Comment: You're confusing numbers with their representation. `15`, `0x0F`, `017`, `0b1111` are all representations of the same number. You can assign any one of them to a `char` and get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any conversion at all:

```
int main()
  char arr[5];
  arr[0] = 0x05;
  int a = arr[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any kind of conversion - `0x05` is already an integer value.

If you have a C string which is the textual representation of a number, then 1. you have to NUL-terminate the string, 2. you can use `strtol()` (or one member of that family of functions):

```
char arr[] = "0x05";
int n = strtol(arr, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: not working. output is 0.

Comment: @kks You kiddin'? [link to working code](http://ideone.com/rsXPLw)

Answer (score 1):

atoi has the following signature:

```
int atoi(const char* buffer);
```

You are passing a non-null terminated buffer to your function. Also your "character" code value is 0x05 which translates to ACK (acknowledgement).
Your number is already 5.
Simply:

```
std::cout << "Number = " << int(arr[0]);
```

Will give you the result you want.

Comment: I need to put this in an integer variable. I dont want cout to print

Comment: No, it won't, as `<<` is overloaded for `char` to output the character. You want `std::cout << "Number = " << int(arr[0]);`

Comment: Yes, indeed you are correct - I had `int arr[5]` in mind when I wrote that. I edited the answer to make it correct.

Comment: @kks I just noticed your comment. I'll add another edit to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You assign 0x05 to char, ascii table tells 0x05 can not convert to any number, atoi function returns 0 if no conversion performed.  That's why you got output of 0