# Formatted output to file just like printf does

Tags: c++

Is it possible to set format of the output to file so I could write to file like printf writes to console?

```
printf("%s\\\n", "something");

std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("somefile", ofstream::in | ofstream::out | ofstream::app); //debug
myfile << ""; // can I use somehow pattern like %s?
```

Comment: What is wrong with `myfile << "something\\\n";`?

Comment: I would like to do something like ""\\x%02x\n" what you will do?!

Comment: what about `fprintf()`?

Comment: @matsuoka, `"\" << std::hex() << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << number << std::endl`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values

Comment: It is usually considered wise to ask not only with the question, but also with use-case for your question. Sometimes stackoverflow may provide you with overall better solution, knowing the context.

Answer (score 2):

```
fprintf(FILE*, ....)
```

but it isn't wise to mix and match.  Use new-style streams wherever possible.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/setf/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a printf-like solution in C++, I'd suggest [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) library:

```
myfile << boost::format("%s\\\n") % "something";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/), it uses *printf()* compatible format strings.