# Output a Unicode Number in C++ (not the character)

Tags: c++, unicode

There's plenty of information out there on how to output unicode Characters in C++.
I'm able to do this with the below code.  This outputs a lower case 'h'.

```
cout << '\u0068' << endl;
```

is it possible to go the other way.  That is, input a 'h' and have cout display the 0068 (unicode number) in a console?

I have googled this to death and found nothing.  I don't want to build a lookup table/switch statement etc.  I though there may be simple way of converting unicode characters into their unicode numbers using something as simple as above.
Any clues.

Comment: Try `cout << hex << '\u0068' << dec << endl;` This requires you to `#include <iomanip>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ cout hex values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values)

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Not only doesn't that answer mention character types, it doesn't mention how to print canonical Unicode form forced to 4 or 8 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that you have to make the type of the datum such that the compiler picks the overloaded `operator<<()` for `cout` that results in numeric output.  You can set the `std::hex` iomanip flag all you want, the type of a `char` or `wchar_t` will always pick the `operator<<()` that outputs a readable character, not the value of it.  To get the compiler to pick the `operator<<()` that will print a value, you have to cast the character as a numeric type.  In my example below, I cast it to a `uint32_t` because 32 bits is sufficient to represent any unicode character.  I could cast it to an `int` on my system since on my system, ints are 32 bits, but to ensure that your code is portable even to tiny embedded systems where `int` is 16 bits and you hardly have enough memory to process ASCII let alone unicode, you should cast it to a type that's guaranteed to be 32 bits or more.  `long` would also be sufficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    cout << hex << '\u0068' << dec << endl;
    wchar_t c;
    std::wcout << "Type a character... " << std::endl;
    std::wcin >> c;
    std::wcout << "Your character was '" << c << "' (unicode "
               << std::hex << std::setw(4) << static_cast<uint32_t>(c) << ")\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me.  The code works too. I never would have figured it out without this.   Have a great day. Thanks again.

Comment: works good with latin chars, but exits on cyrillic input, any ideas why?

Comment: @Drey - Where does it "exit"? And in what manner does it exit? On the `std::wcin >> c;` line or in the `static_cast<uint32_t>(c)`? If you're not sure, break the chained-together last line into separate lines to `std::wcout`, and add `<< std::endl` to the end of each to see better where it's actually exiting. Also possibly step through it with a debugger. (And did you build in 'debug' mode? You might get better debugging info.) I don't know anything about cyrillic characters or how they are stored; do they have unicode representations?

Comment: @phonetagger
by exits I meant I added loop to program to wait for symbol, print its unicode number and wait for char again endlessly. Worked good with latin symbols but exiterd on cyrilic.

>>  I don't know anything about cyrillic characters or how they are stored; do they have unicode representations?
Yes they do (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode)

Your original program outpputs `Your character was '' (unicode    0)`
 on every cyrillic input.

Comment: @Drey - How can I duplicate this behavior? How do I input Cyrillic characters on a U.S. English keyboard? What sort of loop construct did you use? Just `while (true) { ... }`? And to clarify, initially you said the program "exits". To me that means the program terminates abnormally; i.e. it wouldn't have printed "Your character was...", or perhaps printed that but crashed immediately afterward. Now you seem to suggest that the only strange behavior is that it prints nothing for the character, and prints `0` for the number. Does it then somehow unexpectedly exit that `while(true) { ... }` loop?