# C++: Print representation of double in hex

Tags: c++, cout

Is there a simple way to manipulate std::cout so that it prints doubles in their hex representation? In other words, something equivalent to:

```
printf("%" PRIx64, *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t *>(&my_double));
```

To provide some context, I have a program which prints hundreds of floating-point results and I was wondering if there is that magical one-line hack that can print all of them in hex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [**std::hexfloat**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) if you can use C++11

**Example**:

```
double k = 3.14;
std::cout<< std::hexfloat << k << std::endl;
```

prints: **0x1.91eb85p+1**

Comment: Damn, exactly what I needed but g++ does not support it yet.

Comment: Note that this doesn't do the same thing as your `printf` thing (which is also illegal, anyway).

Comment: Wasn't gcc supposed to be fully C++11 compliant?

Comment: Not yet according to this http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

Comment: @jrok Why is my printf illegal?

Comment: It breakes strict aliasing rules.

Comment: It's funny how gcc/clang/icc don't have hexfloat but MSVC does

Comment: The big surprise from MS! :P

Comment: @nccc `memcpy` from `double` to `uint64_t` or ORing bytes together manualy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
    #include <iomanip> //Include this file
    cout<<hex<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned __int64 *>(&r);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get `std::cout` to print in hex with:

```
std::cout << std::hex << num
```