# how to print hex value of an enum to a string in c++

Tags: c++

How do I convert the hex value of the below `enum` to a string and store it in a variable.

```
enum {
    a      = 0x54,
    b,
    c
};
```

For example

```
auto value = a;
std::string value_as_hex = to_hex(a);
```

How do I write `to_hex`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex#Example

Comment: There is no way to figure out if a enum constant was initialized with hex value or in some other way. Thus printing a enum value in hex is no different from printing an arbitrary variable in hex.

Comment: sorry I corrected it ...56 as per the sequence

Comment: Whether you assign a value in decimal (84), hex (0x54) or octal (0124), the value will be stored the same internally. You can only choose to display this value in different ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ cout hex values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values)

Comment: Hexadecimal 56 and decimal 86 (and octal 126, and binary 01010110, and Roman LXXXVI...) denote the same value, the only difference is in their textual form.

Comment: I can print the value in hex or octal with cout. how do I store (hex value) it in a variable to use further?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer to hex string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the hex value of an enum you can use printf with the `%x` placeholder. For example

```
#include <cstdio>

enum Foo {
    a      = 0x54,
    b      = 0xA6,
    c      = 0xFF
};

int main() {
    Foo e;

    e = a;
    printf("%x\n",e);

    e = b;
    printf("%x\n",e);

    e = c;
    printf("%x\n",e);

}
```

the output of the program is

```
54
a6
ff
```

Comment: how do I store (hex value) it in a variable to use further?

Comment: e is a variable.  When I write ``e = a`` the value of the enum `a` is stored in variable `e`.  You can then use e sometime later. Please understand that you don't store a 'hex' value.  When you write ``a = 0x54`` it is the same as writing ``a =84``. The computer has only one way of storing it. What do you want to do with this number later on?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following solution?

```
std::ostringstream str;
str << std::hex << a;
auto x = str.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your `to_hex` function to store the hex representation of the value in a string using stringstreams and IO manipulation :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string to_hex(const unsigned a) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "0x" << std::hex << a;
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    unsigned value = 0x1234;
    std::string value_as_hex = to_hex(value);

    std::cout << value_as_hex << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0x1234
```