# Cannot directly convert number to hex null-terminated string, has to convert to std::string then use .c_str()

Tags: c++, string, hex, stdstring, char-pointer

I've tried to convert an integer to a hex null-terminated (or "C-style") string but I cannot use it with `printf` or my custom log function. It only works if I convert it to an `std::string` then use `.c_str()` when passing it as a parameter, which produces ugly, hard-to-understand code.

It's important to know that using `std::string` and appending to it with `"str +="` does work.

```cpp
const char* IntToHexString(int nDecimalNumber) {
    int nTemp = 0;
    char szHex[128] = { 0 };
    char hex[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' };

    while (nDecimalNumber > 0) {
        nTemp = nDecimalNumber % 16;
        sprintf(szHex, "%s%s", hex[nTemp], szHex);

        nDecimalNumber = nDecimalNumber / 16;
    }

    sprintf(szHex, "0x%s", szHex);
    return szHex;
}
```

I've tried to use Visual Studio Debugger but it doesn't show any error messages, because crashes somewhere in a DLL that has no symbols loaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853487/how-to-print-hex-value-of-an-enum-to-a-string-in-c/53855150#53855150

Comment: `"%s%s"` should be `"%c%s"`. Also, you're returning a stack pointer, Your compiler should issue a warning for both of these. Also, I'm not sure if you can directly write from `szHex` to `szHex` in `sprintf`. Furthermore, why make the return value `const`?

Comment: The behaviour of `sprintf` is undefined if any source string overlaps with the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you define a variable on the stack, locally in the function, and then return it.

After the function returns, the char* will point to "somewhere", to an undefined position. That is a major bug. You have also other bugs that have been commented on already. Like `sprintf(szHex, "0x%s", szHex);`, which is undefined behaviour (UB) or `sprintf(szHex, "%s%s", hex[nTemp], szHex);` which has the same problem + additionally a wrong format string.

The more C++ solution would be, as already shown in many posts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

std::string toHexString(unsigned int hexValue)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "0x" << std::hex << hexValue;
    return std::string(oss.str());
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << toHexString(15) << '\n';
    // or directly
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << 15 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Of course a C-Style solution is also possible.

But all the following I would not recommend:

If you want to stick to C like solution with char *, you could make the `char szHex[128] = { 0 };` static. Or, even better, pass in the pointer to a buffer and return its address, like in

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

char* toHexCharP(unsigned int hexValue, char *outBuffer, const size_t maxSizeOutBuffer)
{
    snprintf(outBuffer,maxSizeOutBuffer-1,"0x%X",hexValue);
    return outBuffer;    
}

constexpr size_t MaxBufSize = 100U;

int main()
{
    char buf[MaxBufSize];
    std::cout << toHexCharP(15, buf, MaxBufSize) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

But as said, I would not recomend. Too dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should look as follows:

```
std::string IntToHexString(int nDecimalNumber) {
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << std::hex << nDecimalNumber;
    return str.str();
}
// ...
std::string transformed = IntToHexString(123);
```

You can then use `transformed.c_str()` to get your string as `const char*`.
Unless you have reasons to do so, you should never work with `const char*` in modern C++. Use `std::string::c_str()` if you need to.