# Convert string into hex format and append "0x " to hex value

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to convert string to hex format and append "0x" prefix to hex value.
For Example:

Input: `std::string s = "0x06A4";`

Output: `int num = 0x06A4`

I have tried this code:

```
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s = "0x06A4";
    int num = std::stoi(s, 0, 16);
    std::cout << "value in decimal     = " << num << '\n';
    std::cout << "value in hexadecimal = " << std::hex << num << '\n';
    ss << "0x" << std::hex << num << '\n'; //
    std::string res = ss.str();
    std::cout << "result  " << res << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ cout hex values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@yogita, std::hex is just one of the configuration you need. You are probably missing the setfill and the setw configuration, as following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s = "0x06A4";

    int num = std::stoi(s, nullptr, 16);
    std::cout << "value in decimal     = " << num << '\n';
    std::cout << "value in hexadecimal = " << std::hex << num << '\n';
    ss << "0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) <<num << '\n';

    std::string res = ss.str();
    std::cout << "result  " << res << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```