# How can I convert unsigned char 0xFF into "FF" string in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I use Hash function to generate a file's hash.the result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH32h.png)

However  I want to get its in string format.

Comment: Question in the title is more or less a duplicate of [C++ cout hex values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479373/c-cout-hex-values). If that does not answer your question, please provide a proper [mre] for your problem and not in an image, but directly as text in the question. See [ask].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that for asking a question here, some research is typically required that should be performed by yourself. Simple search for _c++ unsigned char to hex string_ with Goolge would give you many answers to your question.